# Display only newest post from category on page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not very familiar with PHP so I'm really struggling with this. I have a category called students-of-the-month with an id of 5. I'd like to have one page on my wordpress site that displays only the most recent post from that category. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress: How to display only posts that are in a certain category?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515753/wordpress-how-to-display-only-posts-that-are-in-a-certain-category)

Comment: and [Display recent posts based on their category in Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587958/display-recent-posts-based-on-their-category-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it differently. I found this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

On the page it said this: category-{slug}.php - If the category's slug were news, WordPress would look for category-news.php

This would let me use that page to display any posts in the student of the month category. I'd just program that page to only display the most recent. As for the nav problem, I ended using the "[Page Links To](http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/page-links-to/)" plugin. Thanks for the tips though, they sent me in the correct direction!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the template for showing categories to only list one post per page. By default it shows the `x` most recent posts; if `x` is one, it only shows that one most recent post.